# What does "convey/possess a sense of immediacy" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Such contemporary accounts often **convey a sense of immediacy** and impact...

The opening pages still **convey a sense of immediacy** and excitement...

The challenge of the environmental beat is to **convey a sense of immediacy** 
and pertinence...

Importantly, these acts **possess a sense of immediacy**...

Photographic images usually **possess a sense of immediacy**...

The new issues addressed in this edition **possess a sense of immediacy**...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *convey a sense of immediacy*

The subject (contemporary accounts, opening pages, etc.)

- **expresses a direct influence on the reader**, and/or
- **expresses an urgent call to action** (mostly in a practical sense).

whereas

> *possess a sense of immediacy*

leans more towards the first meaning.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, how we can paraphrase the last sentence? "This edition has new issues that ..."

Comment: And, what you mean by having a tendency to "the first meaning"?

Comment: Is it a good paraphrased versuion? "This edition has new issues which are important and exciting at the present time."

Comment: I mean that 'possess a sense of immediacy' leans more towards the definition of 'expresses a direct influence on the reader'.  Hmm, in that context something like "the new issues addressed in this edition are relevant and pertinent".

Comment: Thank you for comment. Could you please take a look at this page and tell me what they are trying to say: https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/product/Miller-Economics-of-Public-Issues-19th-Edition/9780134018973.html?tab=features

Comment: In Features Tab they say: NEW! The new public issues addressed in this edition possess a sense of immediacy and include the following:.....

Comment: They're trying to say that the issues raised are important (indeed) and of direct influence to their readers; to realize the mechanism behind certain issues, and how to form a proper and informed opinion and possibly act on it.

Comment: Thank you Joachim. And also they're trying to say that these are real-life issues that one may confront or affect all of us nowadays. Ok?

Comment: Correct. They are of *immediate* usefulness.

Comment: Merci beaucoup Joachim :-)

Comment: Hello Joachim. But what about this : " They approached the peace talks with a sense of immediacy. " Could you please tell me what dose " with a sense of immediacy" mean?

Comment: Again, the *they* presented the talks in such a way that the audience would feel the importance, urgency, and/or direct influence the subject has on the lives of the audience.

Comment: thank you, could you please take a look at this question https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/517641/acknowledging-two-sides-of-an-argument-vs-presenting-two-sides-of-an-argument